# how to fixe SQL injection in hibernate(session.createquery())

Tags: java, hibernate

```
org.hibernate.Query hQuery = session.createQuery (String);
hQuery.setParameter(i,data);
```

while scanning code using tool it shows that this line is vulnerable to SQL injeciton. how to fix it.

Comment: It matters what query you are executing. But in general, hibernate uses prepared statements which should be fine.